# sessionid in python changes for first url request

Tags: python, django, apache

can anyone tell me why the session id changes for first url request in python deployed on apache?
eg:
    if i request for www.mysite.com ,i get sessionid=abcd later for 
    next url request like www.mysite.com/something i get sessionid=efgh

just because of this i cant login to my website since i try getting session from session
 table and its giving error.

In django development server its working fine,but its causing error only in apache server.

Comment: What do you mean by 'python deployed on apache'?

Comment: i mean django running on apache

Comment: Do you have multiple mod_wsgi daemons running under this Apache?